# Uploading Textfiles to GCP-Storage with php changes the content of the file

Tags: php, curl, file-upload, google-cloud-platform

I would like to upload a textfile to Google Cloud Storage.
I use this function in php:

```
    function upload_object_to_Google_bucket($bucket,$accesstoken,$proxy,$objectname,$objectpath)
{
#Build the CUrl: incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/".$bucket."/o?uploadType=media&name=".$objectname);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
#    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    $file=$objectpath.$objectname;
    $item=make_curl_file($file);
    print_r($item);
    $file = $objectpath.$objectname;
    $post = array(
    $item
    );
#    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
#    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTP);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
#    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$accesstoken;
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: '.object_to_array($item)["mime"];
    $headers[] = 'Content-Length: '.filesize($file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    print_r($response);
    if (curl_errno($ch)){
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

It's all fine, but the textfile has become new content in the Bucket.

```
    --------------------------9ad622dfd933f230
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="0"; filename="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xml"
Content-Type: text/plain
```

These lines are added to the file. Does anyone has an idea whats the problem and how I can avoid this behaviour?

Comment: Please don't post text as images.

Comment: Sorry, was my first post.

Comment: where is make_curl_file defined? Couldn't find it in [google](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1CAOFPC_enMX893&ei=K_P8Xv21O834tAXzzJ1o&q=%22make_curl_file%22&oq=%22make_curl_file%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIJCAAQsAMQChAeMgkIABCwAxAIEB4yCwgAELADEAgQChAeMgsIABCwAxAIEAoQHlAAWABgt4sOaAJwAHgAgAEAiAEAkgEAmAEAqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwi994as86zqAhVNPK0KHXNmBw0Q4dUDCAw&uact=5)